# Estimating compression ratio for SecureFile LOBs?

Tags: oracle, compression

We made a migration from Oracle 10 to 11.2. Our lob objects are currently stored in the **original** LOB storage architecture. But 11g introduced the **SecureFile**  storage architecture and we want to use its compression feature.

For non-LOB objects we can use something like `dbms_compression.get_compression_ratio` to get compression ratio and forecast estimated space usage.

What is analog for LOBs? Os it impossible to check the compression ratio before converting from basic LOB architecture to SecureFile?

Comment: I don't think there is (see 861344.1 for ideas on how to test). Note that this requires the ACO option, it doesn't come free with 11gR2.

Comment: Thanks for this note @Mat. As i can see, we will made brute test with creating of shortcut copy of existance table for sequential convertion to different levels.